# Prevent from uploading screenshots while using Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server

While the bot is running on Xcode Server, there is a time when screenshots are being uploaded.

[image]

It takes a while to finish processing. So my question is:

**Is there a way to skip this or prevent from uploading?**

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Related: where are they being uploaded _to_?